# What can we say about $1-F(x) = x$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$F(x)$ is a probability distribution.

Is there any useful characterization of the solution to: $1-F(x) = x$? More specifically, can we say anything about the solution in terms of it's relationship to moments of the distribution?

If it helps, suppose the support is $x\in[0,1]$.

Edit: I notice that when $x\in[0,1]$ and F(x) is a symmetric distribution, the solution is equal to the mean.

Note that for a symmetric distribution on $[0,1]$: $E(x)=F(E(x))=.5$

$1-F(E(x))=E(x)
\\
1-F(.5)=.5
\\
1-.5=.5
\\
.5=.5$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem

Comment: I made an answer I suspected to be useful but found flaws in the logic. Thanks @Julius for also pointing this out, as well. In summary:
Notice that $1 - F(x) = x \implies -f(x) = 1$. But this works for $X\sim U(a,b)$, because $1 - F(x) = x\implies 1 - \frac{x}{b-a} = x$ so $x = \frac{b-a}{b-a+1}$. Looks like solutions do exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it would help to know more precisely what kind of characterisations you are looking for.

For example, given that $F(\cdot)$ is continuous and the support is indeed $[0,1]$, then solution $x^*$ is a fixed point of $G(x)=1-F(x),$ and by Brouwer's fixed-point theorem we know that it always exists.

Comment: Thank you. I will be a little more clear.